# Android getting website content using InputStream

Tags: java, android, web

I am trying to get the content of a website (its source) in an Android app.

```java
URL url = new URL("http://verbmaps.com/");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
```

Now this gives a lot of errors when run.

(I have put this is a js snippet so I could hide it)

```js
/*

W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
W/System.err:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:431)
W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:384)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:231)
W/System.err:     at com.example.yeeverbs.MainActivity$override.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
W/System.err:     at com.example.yeeverbs.MainActivity$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
W/System.err:     at com.example.yeeverbs.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:0)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4077)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(ActivityThread.java)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1350)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)


*/
```

One of the errors points to line `41`, which is the line with the `InputStream`:

```java
InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
```

Hence, I was not able to run it successfully.

#### Additional Notes

I have the required permissions in my Android Manifest file

```java
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Also I've seen that several solutions use `DefaultHttpClient` instead of `URL`. I tried it out, but Android Studio tells me it is deprecated. So I had to go back to using `URL` unless there are any other better alternatives that are not deprecated.

Additionally, I'm trying to do this without any external libraries, so I am not going to accept `JSoup` or any other such libraries.

#### In short,

I am getting the source of a website using `URL`. However `InputStream` is giving me errors.

I want to know why this is happening. Also any better alternatives that are not deprecated or are external libraries to this task will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, you are doing networking calls on the main thread. In android, you should do any such calls in a background thread. Hint: scheck asyncTasks

Comment: Could you give me a more detailed example of what you mean? I understand what you are trying to say, but I don't understand your approach to it is

Comment: You can find some useful approaches in the link [link]https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html[/link]

You will have to move the above code snippet into the askynTask class and then call the askyncTask from your main code

Answer (score 0):

Use this, should work.

```
public static String getResponseFromUrl(String url) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); /
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL); 
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget); 
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
        InputStream is = entity.getContent(); 
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(line);

        String resString = sb.toString(); 

        is.close();
        return  resString; 
        }
```

And like say in the comment, use this in different thread, no main thread.

Comment: `HttpClient` is also deprecated

Comment: Sure but can use @KritixiLithos :

android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

Comment: I have that in my gradle, but it still says it is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

create a class and extend Async Task because you can't do this thing on main thread

```
       class webdownload extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try{
                String result="";
                URL url =new URL(urls[0]);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                int data = reader.read();

                while (data!=-1){
                    char current = (char) data;
                    result += current;
                    data = reader.read();
                }
                return result;
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

now create a function to execute

```
public void Scrape(View view){

         String htmlcontent;

         webdownload wb= new webdownload();

        try {
            htmlcontent = wb.execute("YOUR_WEBSITE_LINK").get();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```